# Running a Linux webserver on premises in a heterogeneous LAN?

Tags: networking, dns, routing, webserver, erp

In the context of [running](https://askubuntu.com/q/1292425/847449) the `Odoo` opensource `ERP` on premises in small office LAN environment, what are the general considerations at setup, insofar as routing and `DNS` goes?

Assuming that `Odoo` is running in `docker` on a `Linux` box, how would a user on a `Windows` PC navigate to the web server itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what exactly you are asking, but normally LAN setups in small offices work like this (ignoring DMZ for publicly accessible services in your company, if you have any):

- Single "internal" LAN segment
- One DHCP service and one DNS service for this LAN segment
- One LAN segment gateway to your ISP

"Home router" devices typically provide this on a single device, but are often not very flexible in configuration. So you may keep this setup and re-flash an off-the-shelf homerouter with OpenWRT etc., or provide your own service on real or virtual hardware.

If you use e.g. `dnsmasq` (which is typically used on home routers), then devices in your LAN can announce their own hostname via DHCP, and get the DNS server to add this as a dynamic entry. All other computers in this LAN can then do DNS lookup, and access this machine.

For services inside Docker on a Linux box inside this LAN, you can either (1) use [macvlan networking](https://docs.docker.com/network/macvlan/) to configure Docker so the container appears as an external device in the LAN, and can participate in the DHCP process, or (2) your container must use Dynamic DNS (DDNS) to announce itself to the DNS server, and the DNS server must understand this (I think `dnsmasq` doesn't, but I may be wrong), or (3) you use the hostname of the Linux host for the container, as the container port will externally be accessible on the host, or (4) you set up static name resolution, which you then must update as required every time you make changes.

All of this is completely independent of `Odoo` or anything else you'd like to run as a service in your LAN.

If you do not have enough networking experience to set this up yourself, get professional help; after all, it's for a business environment.